# iCal re-occuring events never end on iPhone

Tags: iphone, calendar, icalendar

I have some code which generates calendar entries for an ical file that is hosted on a publicly accessible web-server. Here is a trimmed down version:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//customical//me//
X-WR-CALNAME:Testing
:
: (other calendar entries)
:
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120723T140000
DURATION:PT60M
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20120806T2359590
LOCATION:Room 1
SUMMARY:Daily appointment
CATEGORIES:(none)
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:This is a daily appointment
END:VEVENT
:
: (other calendar entries)
:
END:VCALENDAR
```

If you subscribe to this through Google Calendar, then the calendar entry starts on 23rd July 2012, re-occurs every day and ends 6th August 2012. Brilliant.

However, if you subscribe to this directly from an iPhone running iOS 6, then the calendar entry starts on 23rd July 2012, re-occurs every day and never ends!

Before I write this off as a iOS defect (and attempt to work around it by not including appointments that have expired), is there something I can change in the iCal file to make the iPhone correctly end the appointment at the right time?

Comment: not sure if enough to kill the iPhone calendar but your end date is not valid: have you tried with `20120806T235959` instead of `20120806T2359590`

Comment: That was it! Turns out that the next line used & instead of + (in javascript) to append a value which was adding a trailing 0 to the date. At a guess, iOS treated the date as invalid and completely ignored it (whereas Google ignored any additional trailing data that didn't make sense) which is why the appointment would never end. Many thanks!